# importing the request library into AWS Lambda on node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-lambda

I am calling the request library with `const request = require("request")`

[image]

and I added the dependency in the package.json I have posted the error below. 
From reading other posts however, I realize i might need to npm-install the request module and import the entire zip as a folder.

Since I am new to node, I wanted to check if there is another way to import the 'require' library into the current working directory or am I making a mistake somewhere else ?

Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "fact",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "ask-sdk-core": "^2.0.0",
    "ask-sdk-model": "^1.0.0",
    "i18next": "^15.0.5",
     "request": "^2.88.0"
  }
}
```

its still giving me the following error when I test:

```
Response:
{
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
  "errorMessage": "Error: Cannot find module 'request'",
  "trace": [
    "Runtime.ImportModuleError: Error: Cannot find module 'request'",
    "    at _loadUserApp (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:100:13)",
    "    at Object.module.exports.load (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:140:17)",
    "    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/index.js:45:30)",
    "    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)",
    "    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)",
    "    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)",
    "    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)",
    "    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)",
    "    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)",
    "    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)"
  ]
}

Request ID:
"01b4df3d-e269-4d8a-90a3-7f02b9be9b58"

Function Logs:
START RequestId: 01b4df3d-e269-4d8a-90a3-7f02b9be9b58 Version: $LATEST
2020-04-03T18:02:05.453Z    undefined   ERROR   Uncaught Exception  {"errorType":"Runtime.ImportModuleError","errorMessage":"Error: Cannot find module 'request'","stack":["Runtime.ImportModuleError: Error: Cannot find module 'request'","    at _loadUserApp (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:100:13)","    at Object.module.exports.load (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:140:17)","    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/index.js:45:30)","    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)","    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)","    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)","    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)","    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)","    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)","    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)"]}
END RequestId: 01b4df3d-e269-4d8a-90a3-7f02b9be9b58
REPORT RequestId: 01b4df3d-e269-4d8a-90a3-7f02b9be9b58  Duration: 2159.04 ms    Billed Duration: 2200 ms    Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 19 MB  
Unknown application error occurred
Runtime.ImportModuleError
```

Here is the location where I am using the request: 
For context its an event handler for an Alexa request.

```
const checkprof_Handler =  {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        const request = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request;
        return request.type === 'IntentRequest' && request.intent.name === 'checkprof' ;
    },
    handle(handlerInput) {
        const request = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request;
        const responseBuilder = handlerInput.responseBuilder;
        let sessionAttributes = handlerInput.attributesManager.getSessionAttributes();

        let say = 'Let me check. ';

        let slotStatus = '';
        let resolvedSlot;

        let slotValues = getSlotValues(request.intent.slots); 


        // getSlotValues returns .heardAs, .resolved, and .isValidated for each slot, according to request slot status codes ER_SUCCESS_MATCH, ER_SUCCESS_NO_MATCH, or traditional simple request slot without resolutions

        // console.log('***** slotValues: ' +  JSON.stringify(slotValues, null, 2));
        //   SLOT: name 
        if (slotValues.name.heardAs) {
            slotStatus += ' slot name was heard as ' + slotValues.name.heardAs + '. ';

            var name = slotValues.name.heardAs;
            const url = `http://bluetooth-env-test.eba-brqgvwur.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/WebApp/search.php/
            ${name}`;

            request.get(url, (error, response, body) => {
            let json = JSON.parse(body);
            console.log('error:', error); // Print the error if one occurred
            console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); // Print the response status code if a response was received
            console.log('body:', body); // Print the body

            // const theFact = body;                  
            // const speechOutput = theFact;
            // this.response.cardRenderer(SKILL_NAME, theFact);
            // this.response.speak(speechOutput + " Would you like another fact?").listen("Would you like another fact?");
            // this.emit(':responseReady');
        });

            slotStatus +=  slotValues.name.heardAs ;
        } else {
            slotStatus += 'slot name is empty. ';
        }
        if (slotValues.name.ERstatus === 'ER_SUCCESS_MATCH') {
            slotStatus += 'a valid ';
            if(slotValues.name.resolved !== slotValues.name.heardAs) {
                slotStatus += 'synonym for ' + slotValues.name.resolved + '. '; 
                } else {
                slotStatus += 'match. '
            } // else {
                //
        }
        if (slotValues.name.ERstatus === 'ER_SUCCESS_NO_MATCH') {
            slotStatus += 'which did not match any slot value. ';
            console.log('***** consider adding "' + slotValues.name.heardAs + '" to the custom slot type used by slot name! '); 
        }

        if( (slotValues.name.ERstatus === 'ER_SUCCESS_NO_MATCH') ||  (!slotValues.name.heardAs) ) {
            slotStatus += 'A few valid values are, ' + sayArray(getExampleSlotValues('checkprof','name'), 'or');
        }

        say += slotStatus;


        return responseBuilder
            .speak(say)
            .reprompt('try again, ' + say)
            .getResponse();
    },
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to install the library with npm.
As far I know you have two simple ways to do it, using [aws cloud9](https://aws.amazon.com/cloud9/) or do it in your local environment and upload the lambda to aws.

In order to do that from your local environment, just download your function as a zip, doing click on export function and selecting "Download deployment package":

[image]

This will donwload a zip to your local environment, unzip it and inside the folder, open the terminal and install your dependency:

```
npm i request
```

zip the folder again and deploy it to aws using the aws-cli:

```
aws lambda update-function-code --function-name=your_function_name --zip-file fileb://your_zip_file_name.zip
```

Comment: can I upload it via the GUI ? is there a difference using the AWS-CLI (I dont have it setup right now)?

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to create node Module folder in lambda function.Just create a folder and in that install required i.e npm install require and add it to layer in lambda function. For further information refer https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/lambda-layers-2f80b9211318/

note: use appropriate runtime i.e all available version of nodejs